# swift change tab bar title font

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uitabbarcontroller

I wonder how I can change the font and size of title in my tabs when I use tab bar.

I have looked in the docs and I cant find anything about title font and size - [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarItem)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change it via the appearance proxy:

```
let font: UIFont = ...
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: .Normal)
```

**Swift 4:**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], for: .normal)
```

You should put this in your app delegate in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

Comment: @user2636197 see the updated answer and please accept if this works for you

Comment: I get error: value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'titleTextAttributes'

Comment: @user2636197 my bad, check the new edit. You had to specify the state. The `.Normal` state will set it for normal, and the other states will fall back on this value.

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone but my font does not change

Answer (score 2):

Update for swift 3.

Put this in your app delegate in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: yourFont], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
guard let font: UIFont = UIFont(font: "arial", size: 15) else { return }
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: font], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this **Swift 5** solution to be useful:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this solution worked for me (Swift 5.5):

```
let fontSize: CGFloat = 12
      
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
    ]
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
    ]
} else {
     if #available(iOS 11, *) {
         UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
         ], for: .normal)
         UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
         ], for: .selected)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 Worked for me

Add this code to mainTabView

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], for: .normal)
```